# How to add coin score so player accumulates more and more over time, swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I created a score and high score label. The score gets 1 pint each time the player hits a coin, the high score gets updated every time the score is higher then the high score. Now, besides this I want to change the function of the score. I don't want it to start from 0 each time the game restarts, I want it to start at the last amount the player won during the previous game. So pretty much just a score label that keeps accumulating more and more points over time even when the player shuts down the app.

This is my current code with the normal score that starts from 0 each time the player starts the game and a highscore that gets updated each time the score reaches a higher amount then the high score.

```
let highScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

var score: Int {

    switch (self) {

    case coin: return 1

    default: return 0

    }
}

func playerScoreUpdate() {
    playerScorelabel.text = "Score: \(playerScore)"
}

func saveHighScore(high:Int) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(high, forKey: "highscore")
}
func highScore() -> Int {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
}
func resetHighScore() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("highscore")
}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }


    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(shipCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(obstacleCategory)) != 0 {
        ship.removeFromParent()
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let scene = GameOverScene(size: self.size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(shipCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(coinCategory)) != 0 {
        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent() // Changed line.
        playerScore = playerScore + 1
        playerScoreUpdate()
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(shipCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(diamondCategory)) != 0 {
        secondBody.node?.removeFromParent() // Changed line.
    }

    //CHANGE TO YOU WON SCENE
    //CHECK TO SEE IF COINS ARE 10, THEN YOU WON
    if playerScore == 30 {

        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let scene = GameWonScene(size: self.size)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)

    }

    if playerScore > highScore() {
        saveHighScore(playerScore)
        println("New Highscore = " + highScore().description)
        highScoreLabel.text = "HighScore: \(highScore().description)"

    } else {
        println("HighScore = " + highScore().description )  // "HighScore = 100"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didMoveToView` method, you can just set the value of your highscoreLabel to the value of your `highScore()` method:

```
playerScore = highScore()
```

Then you should be able to start at the last highScore. You shouldn't have to change something else, because the other parts of your code should do their parts well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Christian ! I really appreciate it and seems to work. Now everytime I start the game the score will be 0 and jumps to lets say 31 if the first coin is added. How can I tell the score to start with that number rather then start with 0? Thank you !

Comment: I actually figured it out myself already. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it !